# how to set array of args for scheduled event?

Tags: events, cron, actions

I have a scheduled event that runs twice daily in my plugin, the action is registered with

```
add_action('fhprw_action','fhprw_check_fetch'); 

function fhprw_check_fetch($args){
  $type=$args['type'];

//do stuff according to $type
}
```

if I manually call a `do_action('fhprw_action',array('type'=>'uk'));` when a widget is updated then the function receives $args as an array and I can get $type from $args['type'] no problem

but when I schedule an event with

```
wp_schedule_event(time() , 'twicedaily', 'fhprw_action',array('type'=>$instance['type'])); // ($instance['type'] will be 'uk')
```

then the function receives $args as a string

$args = 'uk' instead of array('type'=>'uk');

why is the function not receiving an array for $args when it is called by the cron?

[edit]

scheduled events call the callback function with a list of parameters, not an array of parameters so my callback function for the action would receive $arg1,$arg2 etc and wouldn't be able to accept an associative array

Answer (score 1):

It could be the phrasing of the array so try setting the array outside the `wp_schedule_event` call:

```
$args = array('type'=>$instance['type']);
wp_schedule_event(time() , 'twicedaily', 'fhprw_action',$args);
```

Comment: turns out that a scheduled event will call the callback function with `call_user_func_array` which means the function is called with fhprw_check_fetch($arg1,$arg2,$arg3) and not fhprw_check_fetch($arrarg);

Comment: In which case, if you really wanted args passed back as an associative array, you could schedule with `$args = array( array( 'type' => $instance['type'] ) );`